# how to open links one by one from excel using selenium java?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an excel with 5 different links in first five rows and first column in the excel. Now I need to open all this five links one after the other. This is the code I have tried

```
 @DataProvider(name="URLS")
  //  @Test
    public Object[][] readFromExcel() throws IOException {

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook("pagelinks.xlsx");

        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("URL");

        int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        int columns = sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
        Object [][]urls=new Object[lastRowNum][columns];

        for(int i=1;i<=lastRowNum;i++){
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
            for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
                XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
                urls[i-1][j]=cell.getStringCellValue();
            }
           // String url = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
            //System.out.println(url);
        }

return urls;
    }
 public WebDriver initializedriver() {
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Natesh\\Automation\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
      return driver;
 }

    @Test(dataProvider = "URLS")
    public void logInMethod(String url) throws Exception{
        
        driver.get(url);
        
    }
```

with this code the first link is fetched from the excel and it is opening in the browser but it stops there it is not reading the second link. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: This is not a web driver or Selenium issue. This is a simple looping issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an entity that contains multiple URLs (i.e. a spreadsheet), you need a regular Java process to fetch the data (loop thru the rows or columns), and then make calls for the web driver to open each URL either as tabs or as separate windows. The easiest way to do this is something like this:

```
WebDriver driver = initializedriver();
// more code here?
for(int i=1;i<=lastRowNum;i++){
    XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
    for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
        XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
        urls[i-1][j]=cell.getStringCellValue();
    }
    String url = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
    driver.get(url); // assuming the loop you created works correctly
}
```